# Can't remove Wordpress post image height/width attributes?

Tags: css, images

I know a few people have asked this question previously; however, I think something may have changed recently in the Wordpress update.

I'm building my own responsive theme for my portfolio, and for embedded post images I have added a filter to functions.php to remove the height/width attribute that Wordpress adds to the image automatically. I have used this filter before on other sites therefore I know it should work.

However, no matter what I try I can't get Wordpress to embed the image without the height/width attributes, meaning the image doesn't resize on mobiles/tablets.

Demo for the image in question is here:

http://demo.iamdannygreen.com/cients/dragonfly-pr/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Danny

Comment: this was originally a cross-post, after migration now a dupe of [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76770/how-can-i-remove-height-width-attribute-from-post-images)

Answer (score 1):

Is this through the post thumbnail functions, or TinyMCE?

If it's through the post thumbnail, you should be able to blank out those attributes like this:

```
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('height' => '', 'width' => ''));
```